# Can I use @Query and @Body together in Retrofit2.0?

Tags: retrofit2

I use @Query and @Body together,but the server can't receive Body'datas.Why?

```
@POST("http:XXXXXXXreceive_data.json")
Observable<HttpResponse<List<String>>> uploadMultipleTypeFile(@Query("token") String token,
                                                              @Body MyBody myBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Body annotation defines a single request body .
That mean if you are using @body it should be the only parameter.It is helpful when you have already a JsonObject and you want to send it as it with you api call.
Another way is, you can convert object to json String using Gson library and send it as a JSON string.